# Is there really `ResultSet.getObject(String, Class<T>) in JDK7?

Tags: java, compatibility, java-7

I see quite a few changed interfaces in JDK7, e.g., the addition of `ResultSet.getObject(String, Class<T>)`. I was greatly surprised by this incompatible change, especially because I've never seen it discussed.

I suppose the incompatibility doesn't matter when I use a JAR file instead of trying to compile the project myself, right?

What is the proper way to support both JDK6 and JDK7? Does simply implementing the new methods and never using them suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems

```
<T> T getObject(int columnIndex, Class<T> type) throws SQLException
```

and

```
<T> T getObject(String columnLabel,  Class<T> type) throws SQLException
```

were introduced in 1.7. (At least it says "Since 1.7") in [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.ml#getObject%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29). I agree, it's kind of a nasty change.

There are more changes in the `java.sql` interfaces. `Connection` for instance, got 5 new methods in 1.7. Hopefully the breaking changes are worthwhile.

> ***Does simply implementing the new methods and never using them suffice?***

Yes, but avoid using the `@Overrides` annotation on methods not present in the earlier version of the interface.

Comment: I can live with it, but isn't it the first time ever that such incompatible changes were introduced in new Java version?

Comment: Hehe, yes, except for a few minor things... Variables named `enum` was allowed prior to Java 1.5 for instance :-) Can't think of any breaking changes in the API though.

Comment: @maaartinus No, the java.sql interfaces were extended before from 1.1 to 1.2. (This was the death hit to my fun project to implement an JDBC engine in memory, then: suddenly I had to implement many more methods.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Eclipse, I would read  the [ResultSet javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html).

Comment: I've found it in the meantime and there's really`since 1.7`.

Comment: The 'old' methods are still there, too

Comment: @michael667, yes, but introducing new methods in an interface is still a breaking change. (I agree that it would be *much worse* to actually *remove* methods from the interface though!)

Comment: Adding methods breaks old implementers, while removing methods breaks old users of the interface. (Maybe the engine here uses some proxy magic to implement it for old drivers.)

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-implement these methods, but you will not be able to use the `@Override` annotation.  Looks like Java 7 doesn't define any new types which would prevent you from implementing the new methods in Java 6 but this is not always the case (e.g. usages of [`SavePoint`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#rollback%28java.sql.Savepoint%29) in Java 1.4 but there are many others).