# AbstractMethodError with DelegatingResultSet in Spring ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, spring-jdbc

Using Java 1.8.0_73-b02 and Mysql JDBC Connector 5.1.39, I'm trying to start using the `ResultSet.getObject()` method but I get an AbstractMethodError when I call it:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method org/apache/tomcat/dbcp/dbcp/DelegatingResultSet.getObject(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; is abstract
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getObject(DelegatingResultSet.java)
    at com.skubana.cerp.dao.model.CarrierShippingPresetDao$1.mapRow(CarrierShippingPresetDao.java:226)
    at com.skubana.cerp.dao.model.CarrierShippingPresetDao$1.mapRow(CarrierShippingPresetDao.java:1)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:693)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:629)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:680)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:712)
```

I know this [was reported elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984853/abstractmethoderror-on-resultset-getobject) but it seems like the solution was to upgrade the connector. I'm using the latest version per the MySql website. Is this method simply unavailable for Mysql?

Comment: This kind of error typically means that you are compiling against one version of a jar and running against another.  What version of Tomcat DBCP are you running with?

Comment: This error means that your DBCP code is (very) out of date.

Comment: I'm not sure how to determine that but I will look into it

Comment: It looks like I'm using `org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-dbcp:7.0.57`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments are correct, it is because of the version.

The answer is explained here:

[AbstractMethodError on resultset.getObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984853/abstractmethoderror-on-resultset-getobject)